# Select only (1) random choice from mysql database output of over 100 items

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a function `get_user_agent` that returns a few hundred rows from a mysql database. A subset of these nearly 100+ results looks like:

The output of each user agent looks like (just with like 100 more entries, this is just one):

**UPDATED OUTPUT FROM MYSQL QUERY**

```
[(('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/418.9.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3 TeaShark/0.8',), ('Mozilla/5.0 (Nintendo WiiU) AppleWebKit/534.52 (KHTML, like Gecko) NX/2.1.0.8.21 NintendoBrowser/1.0.0.7494.US',))]
```

I am successfully pulling all of the user agents from the database, but I only want to select **1** from there, to use.

Im currently using:
`user_agent = str(random.choice(self.valid_user_agents)`

But this selects the whole *query results* as **1**, when i really only wanted *one user agent* instead it has 100 or more database results as the value of var `user_agent`.

How can I just select **only one** from `user_agent` output ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please paste a few lines of `print(valid_user_agents)` for us?

Comment: @MarcosModenesi - see above

Comment: @MarcosModenesi - i also reworded it too, to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused by the structure of `valid_user_agents`:

```
[                                     # A list
    (                                 # containing just a tuple
        ('Mozilla/5.0 (Mac...',),     # of tuples of 1 string
        ('Mozilla/5.0 (Nin...',),
        ...      
    )
]
```

so

- `valid_user_agents` -> the whole structure
- `valid_user_agents[0]` -> the inner (big) tuple
- `valid_user_agents[0][0]` -> a tuple containing the first user agent
- `valid_user_agents[0][0][0]` -> the first user agent as a string

Forget about `random` for a minute and think about how would you go to choose the first user agent (as a string)

```
valid_user_agents[0][0][0]
```

and the second

```
valid_user_agents[0][1][0]
```

and the nth

```
valid_user_agents[0][n][0]
```

Three solutions I see:

#### choose a random integer

choose a random integer `i`from the interval `[0, len(valid_user_agents[0]))` and access `valid_user_agents[0][i][0]` (note it's a closed interval on the left and open on the right, meaning the lowest possible value is 0 and the highest is the length of `valid_user_agents[0]`-aka "the big inner tuple"- minus 1). Minimum example:

```
import random
i = random.randint(0, len(valid_user_agents[0]) - 1)
# NOTE: i is a random discrete variable whose sampling space is the
# set {0, 1, 2, ..., length of the big inner tuple - 1}
# meaning it's a valid index for that inner big tuple

user_agent = valid_user_agents[0][i][0]
```

#### flatten your data structure

Do some manipulations of your data structure to get only what you are interested in in the first level `['Mozilla...', 'Mozilla...', ...]`. Minimum example:

```
valid_user_agents = [ua[0] for ua in valid_user_agents[0]]
user_agent = random.choice(valid_user_agents)
```

#### If possible, change your `sql_query`

This is just based on an assumption.

`SELECT * FROM` tends to give rows as tuples, even if there's only one element in the row. `SELECT column_name FROM` instead, returns a data structure with one less level of depth.

Comment: thanks. I am using `SELECT <col>` not `SELECT *`  Anyway you could elaborate on the selecting a random user agent? Thanks again

Comment: Added a minimum example

Comment: wow, you are a life saver, and dusted off some cobb webs for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad I could help. Added an example to the second solution. I think that is the best one, by the way. It will make your code more clear to others.

Answer (score 0):

Can we get structure of your user agent array, it seems you are running on random on wrong depth of array or tuple

```
import random

data=(('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; NOKIA; Lumia 735) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0',),('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/418.9.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3 TeaShark/0.8'),('Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10A523 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/6.0.1;FBBV/180945;FBDV/iPad2,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/6.0.1;FBSS/1; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/1]'),)

user_agent = str(random.choice(data))

print(user_agent)
```

[Execution](https://repl.it/F7Ex/1)

Comment: Its a `tuple` that looks like `The output` above. I want to turn it into a list, and select just 1 list item randomly.

Comment: Please check link included you don't need to turn it to list

Comment: Thanks for that.Although, I get this error of `Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` on this line: `user_agent = str(random.choice(str.valid_user_agents))`

Comment: Are you missing self.valid_user_agents, as seems your valid_user_agents is empty. Could you post printout of self.valid_user_agents

Comment: See updated output from the db. This is 2 useragents from over a 100

Comment: so as I stated you are having one more array in depth you should use following random.choice(self.valid_user_agents[0])

Comment: I get an error of: user_agent = random.choice(self.valid_user_agents[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134842/discussion-between-iklinac-and-jshee).